# How do I find record of first match and use it later with awk

Tags: awk, text-processing

Suppose the following `time.log` entries

```
Time is now 11 and the weather is windy
Time is now 12 and the weather is nice and there are 2 cats
New animals observed 8 dogs
Time is now 13 and the weather is cold
Time is now 14 and the weather is nice
...
Time is now 10 and the weather is cold on the next morning 
New animals observed 4 cats
Time is now 11 and the weather is warm
```

Now I want to find and save the record number and content of the first line where `time>11` in a generic way, knowing that the time value is recorded periodically throughout the file but not knowing any details of where the first occurrence is.

I tried with the following awk script

```
awk '
  /Time is now/ && $4+0>11 {firstrecord=NR; exit}
  END {print "First occurrence found on line: " firstrecord, $0}
 '
```

This of course works, but the problem is that I need to process the entire file. I cant just exit on the first occurrence. Ideally, the script that I need is something similar to the following pseudo code:

```
awk '
  BEGIN {totalcats=0; totaldogs=0}
  /Time is now/ && $4+0>11 {firstrecord=NR}
  /searchpattern for cats/ {totalcats+=cats_counted_in_this_record}
  /searchpattern for dogs/ {totaldogs+=dogs_counted_in_this_record}
  END {
    printf "We found a total of %d cats and %d dogs in this log.", totalcats, totaldogs;
    print "First occurrence was found on line: " firstrecord, $firstrecord_content}
 '
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check your variable `firstrecord` to make sure that block is run only once:

```sh
awk '
  BEGIN {totalcats=0; totaldogs=0}
  !firstrecord && /Time is now/ && $4+0>11 {firstrecord=NR; rec=$0}
  /searchpattern for cats/ {totalcats+=cats_counted_in_this_record}
  /searchpattern for dogs/ {totaldogs+=dogs_counted_in_this_record}
  END {
    printf "We found a total of %d cats and %d dogs in this log.\n", totalcats, totaldogs
    print "First occurrence was found on line: " firstrecord, rec}
 ' file
```